# Windows Phone deployment - no target listed

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to test a windows phone app. My account is registered as a developer, the phone is registered, and is visible in Zune, but there is no device visible in the targets list. What can I change to make the phone show up in the targets list?

I am using:
Nokia Lumia 710 (Windows Phone 7, version 7.10.8773.98),
A laptop with Windows 8 (64-bit),
Windows Phone SDK 7.1,
Zune 4.8.2345.0

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that there are compatibility issues between Windows 8 and Windows Phone SDK 7.1, that are solved using the following update: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29233

I already had this update installed, but needed to go to the control panel and repair the program (listed as "Windows Phone SDK 7.1 - ENU"). After that finished, I opened XapDeploy.exe once again, and my device was listed, along with the emulators!

Take-home message: if your targets list is empty, install the update linked above. If it's already been installed, repair the installation.